# How to use spark to write to HBase using multi-thread

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I'm using spark to write data to HBase, but at the writing stage, only one executor and one core are executing.
I wonder why my code is not writing properly or what should I do to make it write faster?

[image: spark-UI image-1]

[image: spark-UI image-2]

Here is my code:

```
  val df = ss.sql("SQL")
  HBaseTableWriterUtil.hbaseWrite(ss, tableList, df)

  def hbaseWrite(ss:SparkSession,tableList: List[String], df:DataFrame): Unit ={
    val tableName = tableList(0)
    val rowKeyName = tableList(4)
    val rowKeyType = tableList(5)

    hbaseConf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, s"${tableName}")
    //写入到HBase
    val sc = ss.sparkContext
    sc.hadoopConfiguration.addResource(hbaseConf)

    val columns = df.columns
    val result = df.rdd.mapPartitions(par=>{
      par.map(row=>{
        var rowkey:String =""
        if("String".equals(rowKeyType)){
          rowkey = row.getAs[String](rowKeyName)
        }else if("Long".equals(rowKeyType)){
          rowkey =  row.getAs[Long](rowKeyName).toString
        }
        val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowkey))
        for(name<-columns){
          var value = row.get(row.fieldIndex(name))
          if(value!=null){
            put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"),Bytes.toBytes(name),Bytes.toBytes(value.toString))
          }
        }
        (new ImmutableBytesWritable,put)
      })
    })
    val job = Job.getInstance(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
    job.setOutputKeyClass(classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable])
    job.setOutputValueClass(classOf[Result])
    job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]])
    result.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration)
  }
```

Comment: Which cluster mode are you using?

Comment: @Mohana B C cluster mode，my command is :spark-submit --class com.nari.sgp.maflcc.lifeAnalEval.lcAssetLife.LcAssetLifeMain \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--num-executors 5 \
--executor-memory 70g \
--executor-cores 7 \
--jars hdfs:/jars/ojdbc8.jar \
hdfs:/jars/sgp-1.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

You may not control how many parallel execute may write to HBase.
Though you can start multiple Spark jobs in multiThreaded client program.
e.g. You can have a shell script which triggers multiple `spark-submit` command to induce parallelism. Each spark job can work on one set of data independent to each other and push into HBase.

This can also be done using Spark Java/Scala SparkLauncher API using it with Java concurrent API (e.g. Executor framework).

```
val sparkLauncher = new SparkLauncher
//Set Spark properties.only Basic ones are shown here.It will be overridden if properties are set in Main class.
sparkLauncher.setSparkHome("/path/to/SPARK_HOME")
  .setAppResource("/path/to/jar/to/be/executed")
  .setMainClass("MainClassName")
  .setMaster("MasterType like yarn or local[*]")
  .setDeployMode("set deploy mode like cluster")
  .setConf("spark.executor.cores","2")

// Lauch spark application
val sparkLauncher1 = sparkLauncher.startApplication()

//get jobId
val jobAppId = sparkLauncher1.getAppId

//Get status of job launched.THis loop will continuely show statuses like RUNNING,SUBMITED etc.
while (true) {
    println(sparkLauncher1.getState().toString)
}
```

However, the challenge is to track each of them for failure and automatic recovery. It may be tricky specially when partial data is already written into HBase. i.e. A job fails to process the complete set of data assigned to it. You may have to automatically clean the data from HBase before automatically retrigger.